# Calculating probability matrix

Tags: probability

Suppose we have 2 switches.

The transition matrix for the first switch is:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        p_{00}^1=0.45 & p_{01}^1=0.55 \\
        p_{10}^1=0.25 & p_{11}^1=0.75 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which means, for example, probability that it will be on (1) given that it was off (0) at previous time instant is $$ p_{01} = 0.55 $$

Similarly, for the second switch,

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
       p_{00}^2= 0.55 & p_{01}^2=0.45 \\
        p_{10}^2=0.2 & p_{11}^2=0.8 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then how to find the probabilities-

$$
P_{10}, P_{11}, P_{12}
$$

Where, for example, $P_{12}$ means the probability that both switches will be on given that only one of them was on at previous time instant?

I have tried:

$$
P_{10} = p_{00}^1 * p_{10}^2 + p_{10}^1 * p_{00}^2 (=0.2275)
$$

$$
P_{11} = p_{00}^1 * p_{11}^2 + p_{01}^1 * p_{10}^2 + p_{10}^1 * p_{01}^2 + p_{11}^1 * p_{00}^2 (=0.9950)
$$

$$
P_{12} = p_{01}^1 * p_{11}^2 + p_{11}^1 * p_{01}^2 (=0.7775)
$$

Which doesn't seem quite right because their sum should be 1

Comment: It seems P is supposed to denote the transition matrix of the process of the number of switches that are on. What makes you think this is Markov?

Comment: Well my question is part of a more complex problem that involves Markov decision process (like finding the number of switches on at a given time instant). The title could be misleading I guess.

Comment: Except in a few degenerate cases, the process of the number of switches that are on is not Markov. Here, the trouble is that when in state 1, one does not know which of the switches is on and which one is off. Generally speaking, combining several Markov processes together, if some information about their respective values is lost, is a well known way to destroy Markovianity.

Comment: In the actual problem, state is the number of switches on in any time instant. But that is beside the point here. I'm just going to modify the question title.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, and this process is not Markov, in particular, asking about its transition matrix is meaningless.

Comment: Can we say that the two switches operate independently (in the probabilistic term of the word)?

Comment: Sorry but it seems you simply did not read my second comment (second sentence).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (assuming independent and stationary Markovian switch processes)**

Both switches operate as stationary Markov processes. Both have their stationary state probabilities. Let $\pi_1^1,\pi_1^0$ denote the probabilities that the first switch is on or off, respectively. For the other switch let the same be denoted by $\pi_2^1$ and $\pi_2^0$. These probabilities can be calculated based on the two state transition matrices given.

Let's denote the state of the switches at the $n^{th}$ moment by $X_n^1$ and $X_n^2$. Both random variables may take the values $0$ and $1$.

**Hint to calculate** $P_{1,0}$

$$P_{1,0}=P(X_{n}^1=0\cap X_{n}^2=0\mid X_{n-1}^1=1\cap X_{n-1}^2=0\cup X_{n-1}^1=0\cap X_{n-1}^2=1)=$$
$$=\frac{P(X_{n}^1=0\cap X_{n}^2=0\cap X_{n-1}^1=1\cap X_{n-1}^2=0)}{P(X_{n-1}^1=1\cap X_{n-1}^2=0)+ P(X_{n-1}^1=0\cap X_{n-1}^2=1)}+$$
$$+\frac{P(X_{n}^1=0\cap X_{n}^2=0\cap X_{n-1}^1=0\cap X_{n-1}^2=1)}{P(X_{n-1}^1=1\cap X_{n-1}^2=0)+P(X_{n-1}^1=0\cap X_{n-1}^2=1)}.$$

**If** $\{X_n^1\}$ and $\{X_n^2\}$ **are independent and stationary Markov processes** then we can do the calculation. (Without referring to any combined Markov process.)

So,
$$P(X_{n}^1=0\cap X_{n}^2=0\cap X_{n-1}^1=1\cap X_{n-1}^2=0)=$$
$$=P(X_{n}^1=0\cap X_{n-1}^1=1)P(X_{n}^2=0\cap X_{n-1}^2=0)=$$
$$=P(X_{n}^1=0\mid X_{n-1}^1=1)\pi_1^1P(X_{n}^2=0\mid X_{n-1}^2=0)\pi_2^0$$

and

$$P(X_{n-1}^1=1\cap X_{n-1}^2=0)=P(X_{n-1}^1=1)P( X_{n-1}^2=0)=\pi_1^1\pi_2^0,$$

$$P(X_{n-1}^1=0\cap X_{n-1}^2=1)=P(X_{n-1}^1=0)P( X_{n-1}^2=1)=\pi_1^1\pi_2^1.$$

The conditional probabilities are given by the OP and the stationary probabilities can be calculated.

---

**NOTE**

The title of the OP is misleading. It asks for a probability matrix as if the number of switches ON formed a Markov process. This is not the case. Even so, the indexed probabilities $P_{i,j}$ can be calculated. (Here $i,j \in \{0,1,2\}.$)

**ALSO**

Take a look at Did's **notes** below. 
There: "if they are at stationarity" means that my calculations are exact if we set the switches randomly -- at the beginning -- with probabilities $\pi_1^1$, $\pi_1^0$,$\pi_2^1$,$\pi_2^0$.

Comment: "If {X1n} and {X2n} are independent Markov processes then we can do the calculation" And if they are at stationarity.

Comment: @Did: Thx. I fix this immediately.

Comment: Right. A more serious problem, which you might want to address even more squarely in your answer, is that these transition probabilities cannot be used to compute more elaborate probabilities as in Markov processes, for example, if $X=X^1+X^2$ and if $(X^1,X^2)$ are at stationarity, eventhough $$P_\pi(X_{n+1}=x,X_{n}=y)=\pi_yP_{yx},$$ it happens that $$P_\pi(X_{n+2}=x,X_{n+1}=y,X_n=z)\ne\pi_zP_{zy}P_{yx}.$$

Comment: Another point worthy of notice is that, in the context of your answer, $P_{20}\ne0\ne P_{02}$.